# How properly to extend a JS class loaded from an external site in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps-api-3, ecmascript-6

I need to do a couple of things in my app.
1. Load the Google Maps API
2. Init my map
3. Get a reference to the `google` variable, and use it to make an event listener and extend the ImageOverlay class that it contains

Right now I am using [this pattern](http://www.klaasnotfound.com/2016/11/06/making-google-maps-work-with-react/) so I can reference `google` via `window.google`. Then in my initMap, I set up an event listener and do
```

```
ImageOverlay.prototype = new window.google.maps.OverlayView();

function ImageOverlay(bounds, image, map) {
    ...do constructory stuff
  }

  ImageOverlay.prototype.onAdd = function() {

    ...
  };
```

to create the class I need (from [the G Maps docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-simple)). I'd like to move this code to an external file, but I'm stuck on how to clean that up. I get errors such as `'ImageOverlay' is not defined`. If I try to make it into an ES6 class (`export default class ImageOverlay extends window.google.maps.OverlayView {` and then `import ImageOverlay ...`) it fails because `window.google` is not defined yet. So my question is, how can I properly load that class and then extend it? Let me know if I need to provide more detail/clarify anything. TIA.

Alternate problem: I use `react-async-script-loader` to load the API: `export default scriptLoader(['https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=whoop&callback=initMap&libraries=visualization'])(MapContainer)` This component, however, does `import Map` at the top, which, in turn, does `import ImageOverlay`, which of course, fails, because `google` hasn't been defined yet.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, here's how I ended up solving it:

```
import scriptLoader from 'react-async-script-loader'
class MapContainer extends Component {...}

export default scriptLoader(['https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=mykey&libraries=visualization'])(MapContainer)

....

class Map extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    var ImageOverlay = require('../Util/ImageOverlay.js').default;

...
export default class ImageOverlay extends window.google.maps.OverlayView { ... }
```

Biggest thing was using `require(~).default` (which can dynamically import) instead of the import at the top of the React file. Then you can ensure that `window.google.maps` is accessible, and that the class doesn't try to extend that until the api has been loaded. You can even pass `maps` as a prop to the `Map` component.